# BigQuery : add new column to existing tables using python BQ API

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Related question: [Bigquery add columns to table schema using BQ command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702420/bigquery-add-columns-to-table-schema)

I want to add a new column to existing tables (update the existing table's schema) in BigQuery using BigQuery [Python API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.tables.html).

However my code seems not working.

Here's my code:

```
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('secret_key_path', scope='my_scope')
    storage = Storage('CREDENTIAL_PATH')
    credentials = storage.get()
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, tools.argparser.parse_args([]))
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
    tbObject = bigquery_service.tables()
    query_body = {'schema': {'name':'new_column_name', 'type':'STRING'}}
    tbObject.update(projectId='projectId', datasetId='datasetId', tableId='tableId', body=query_body).execute()
```

it returns `Provided schema doesn't match existing table's schema` error. 
Can anyone give me a working Python example?
Many thanks!

Comment: you should provide whole schema, not just new field

Comment: Hi Mikhail, do you mean the whole schema of existing table?

Comment: yes, with new field. so api will be responsible for adding new one. but for this to happen the whole schema needs to be presented

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I have one more question, I know there's no SET and UPDATE methods for BQ, just wondering if I add a new column to existing table, how canI set the value of the new column for existing tables? Or I have to drop the existing table and create a new table with column values?

Comment: Ah I see, I'll try it again with whole schema

Comment: the new field will be added with null for existing rows. no way to set value.

Comment: Oh no, that's very bad, my existing tables are hundred TB big, so does it mean I have to regenerate everything?. Is there any smart way to do this?

Comment: from what I know there is no way to add new field with value for existing rows. for new rows you will have whatever values will come - but not for rows before the field was added. you can have some logic in queries that you will be running against this table to compensate this. or you can have separate table with just this new field and some key that you will be joining your existing table with new table to get this field.

Comment: That make sense, thank you Mikhail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

summary of my comments (as i've got some minutes now for this):

- whole schema (along with new field) needs to be supplied to api
- new field will be added with null for existing rows. no way to set
  value
- you can have some logic in queries that you will be running against
  this table to compensate this. or you can have separate table with
  just this new field and some key that you will be joining your
  existing table with new table to get this field

Comment: More on patch vs. update as it applies to schema updates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17113985/1375400

Answer (score 5):

Base on `Mikhail Berlyant` comments, I have to pass existing table's schema with new field (column) to the `update()` method to update the existing tables's schema.

A python code example is given below:

```
...
tbObject = bigquery_service.tables()
# get current table schema
table_data = tbObject.get(projectId=projectId, datasetId=datasetId, tableId=tableId).execute()
schema = table_data.get('schema')
new_column = {'name': 'new_column_name', 'type': 'STRING'}
# append new field to current table's schema
schema.get('fields').append(new_column)
query_body = {'schema': schema}
tbObject.update(projectId='projectId', datasetId='datasetId', tableId='tableId', body=query_body).execute()
```

And also, there's no way to set value of new columns for existing rows (tables). Thanks for `Mikhail Berlyant` suggestion, the way to set the value for existing rows is to create a seperate table for new columns with values, and join the existing table with that table to replace the old schema table