# "compatible" schemas for bigquery wildcard table query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a set of historical data tables that have different but 'compatible' schemas. What I mean is that over time, the schema has evolved and more fields got added (not removed). I like to run a query over the union of all.

Doing so using `legacy SQL` requires multiple `SELECT` statements joined by `UNION` and dummy NULL placeholders for new fields that did not exist in earlier tables.
I have 100 of those combo queries to build & execute.

I could script this but was hoping using `Standard SQL` wildcard tables instead. I read however at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#tablewildcardfunctions :

> In order to execute a standard SQL query that uses a wildcard table,
>   BigQuery automatically infers the schema for that table. BigQuery uses
>   the schema for the most recently created table that matches the
>   wildcard as the schema for the wildcard table. If the schema is
>   inconsistent across tables matched by the wildcard table, BigQuery
>   returns an error.

Not sure how strict is meant *inconsistent*. Would it support *incremental schema* as per above use case or do all tables need to share the exact same schema ?

If not possible, another alternative would be to (re)load from source into a new table using the schemaUpdateOptions `ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION`. It means redesign and rework.

Any other suggestion is welcome. FYI - I use Airflow to execute the queries so I rather use a Pythonic solution.

Comment: Have you tried running the wildcard table query? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery API has `patch tables` functionality, where you can patch/extend all your old tables with the schema changes that were added by the new structure.

By [patching](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch) the old tables you just add NULL like columns to past schema and data is not deleted.

So what you need to do is write a script that takes the most recent schema, and incrementally patches all previous tables to the new schema and then you can run your `UNION` queries.

Related: [How do I use BigQuery patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098419/how-do-i-use-bigquery-patch)